# What are the steps to create an intuitive and straightforward proof of the optimality of Huffman coding?

Tags: correctness-proof, information-theory, data-compression, huffman-coding

I am having great difficulty following the proof in class. I assume "optimal" means it minimizes the Average bit length to encode an alphabet with known frequencies. My understanding of how the algorithm works is by building a tree in a "bottom up" fashion. The least frequent alphabets are at the bottom and fused into a meta node, and then put back in the queue. Then you compare this reduced alphabet and do the same  and join nodes with each other via an internal node.
To prove this tree will yield the minimum weighted path lend the proof showed in class relied on induction.  For the trivial case where n=2 (or just two reduced alphabet), the tree returned is obviously the minimum that can be produced (with two leaves). Now we have to prove this for all n>2. The inductive hypothesis is the tree at an arbitrary n-1 is correct, i.e returns the minimum weighted path?

Lemma 1 states that  there exists an Optimal tree where the least frequent nodes exist at the bottom of the tree and differ from each other by one bit. For example in a 4 letter alphabet lets say C and D has the coding 110 and 111. **Does this Lemma imply there are other optimal trees (non huffman ones) where the least frequent alphabets are NOT at the deepest level of the tree, and there are also non optimal codes who have C and D at the deepest level as siblings?**  This is using a exchange argument which I can follow,i.e by exchanging C and D with other less frequent letters at a shallower depth we cannot decrease the cost of the tree. Up to here I can follow

Lemma 2 states that if we fuse the nodes into a meta node (CD) this tree (T') will have a cost that varies from the full tree (T) by a fixed amount i.e ABL(T)= ABL(T')+ p(C)+ p(D). Then the book states that this implies that if T is optimal it would also mean T' is optimal. I don't follow how.
Finally combining Lemma 1 and 2 in the inductive step they prove the constructed tree by algorithm is optimal. This is where I completely lose understanding. How can you complete the proof by combining Lemma 1 and 2  Could you please clarify in an intuitive clear way, perhaps by illustrating   with concrete example. For example let us consider  tree over four or 5 alphabets (A, B, C, D) lets say with a probability ( of 0.5, 0.3 0.15, and 0.05), and tie this concrete example back to the inductive proof?